# How to find and remove a string enclosed in HTML in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, regex, string, strip

I have a rather long text which contains some strings that are inside HTML tags (mostly `h1` and `h2`). I need to remove those completely, which means I need a way to find text that is enclosed in certain HTML tags and then strip these away from the original text.

I tried using `gsub` but couldn't figure out how to construct a regex or something that makes sense.

Comment: We can help you, when you have an example input and corresponding output too..

Comment: Arup: thanks for your answer but I guess any HTML is good - as long as there are some headlines in it we can strip away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding and removing nodes is easy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
<p>This is some text</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('h1, h2').remove
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> 
# >> 
# >> <p>This is some text</p>
# >> </body></html>
```

I'm using `search` with a CSS selector `h1, h2` which will find all `<h1>` and `<h2>` nodes and return them as a NodeSet. A NodeSet is like an array; `remove` simply walks that NodeSet and removes all its elements.

If you want to look inside the nodes at their text, expand the code a little:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
<h1>baz</h1>
<p>This is some text</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('h1, h2').select{ |n| n.text[/\b(?:foo|bar)\b/] }.map(&:remove)
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> 
# >> 
# >> <h1>baz</h1>
# >> <p>This is some text</p>
# >> </body></html>
```

`text` returns the text content of a node. `/\b(?:foo|bar)\b/` looks in that text for the words `"foo"` or `"bar"`. That results in an Array, so I can't use the NodeSet's `remove` method. Instead, I can pass it into `map`, which will iterate over each Node that was returned by `select`, and send Nokogiri::Node.select to it. It's a little more convoluted, but gets there.

XPath selectors could look inside the node's text to replace part of the Ruby code, but they'd be pretty ugly. I prefer to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `regex` to parse `HTML` (see "[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1120015)"). You might want to look at an HTML parsing gem like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)

h1s = doc.css('h1').map(&:text)
h2s = doc.css('h2').map(&:text)
```

Comment: Thanks Uri, I will try that. But the thing is - how will I be able to eliminate those found h1s and h2s and retain the rest of the text?

Comment: You should read `nokogiri`'s documentation. You can manipulate the parsed HTML, remove tags, etc.